# $watch only firing on reload

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, ngroute

I have a page that has 3 sections. I'm using ui-router, and I'm using an abstract view to get the vehicle object.
In the second view, I need to compute a field based on the vehicle object, I'm using a $scope.$watch. 
The problem that I have is that when the state changes to 'dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard.proof' the watch method is called once, but the vehicle is undefined, and it doesn't get hit a second time. If I reload the page tho, it gets hit.

any idea ?

```
  .state 'dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard',
      url: "vehicle"
      templateUrl: 'views/vehicle-wizard.html'
      controller: 'VehicleWizardCtrl'
      abstract: true

  .state 'dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard.info',
      url: "/info"
      templateUrl: 'views/vehicle-info.html'
      controller: 'VehicleInfoCtrl'

  .state 'dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard.proof',
      url: "/proof"
      templateUrl: 'views/vehicle-proof.html'
      controller: 'VehicleProofCtrl'
```

VehicleWizardCtrl :

```
angular.module 'App'
.controller 'VehicleWizardCtrl', ($scope, $state, vehicle) ->

    vehicle.get().then (result) ->
      if result
        $scope.vehicle = result[result.length - 1]
```

VehicleInfoCtrl:

```
$scope.submit = ->
  return if !$scope.form.$valid
  $scope.loading = true
  $scope.vehicle.status = "confirmed"
  $scope.vehicle.update()
  .then (vehicle) ->
    $scope.loading = false
    $scope.vehicle = vehicle
    $state.go "dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard.proof", $scope.vehicle
  , (resp, headers) ->
    $scope.loading = false
    _.each resp.data, (errors, key) ->
      if $scope.form[key]
        $scope.server_errors[key] = errors[0]
        $scope.form[key].$error["server"] = errors[0]
        $scope.form[key].$setValidity('server', false)
```

VehicleProofCtrl :

```
$scope.$watch('vehicle', (newValue, oldValue)->
  if ($scope.vehicle)
    $scope.vehicle.age = parseInt(moment($scope.vehicle.regDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow(true).match(/\d+/g))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$watchCollection` insted of `$watch`

`$watchCollection` watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for array items and object maps, this implies watching the properties). If a change is detected, the listener callback is fired.

for further info [read doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: that still doesn't work on the first load, but works if I reload

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a [deepwatch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for objects and that can be done by passing true as the 3rd parameter:

```
$scope.$watch('vehicle', (newValue, oldValue)->
  if ($scope.vehicle)
    $scope.vehicle.age = parseInt(moment($scope.vehicle.regDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow(true).match(/\d+/g))
, true)
```